# How do I swim to the big frog statue without standing on anything?

Tags: here-comes-niko

In Salmon Creek Forest, after getting the Contract List from Tadpole HQ, the Game Kid has a mission to swim from his location to the big frog statue without standing on anything. How do I reach the frog statue without touching the ground?

[image: Game Kid saying not to stand on anything]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This took way too long to figure out, here's a step by step guide. Keep in mind if the face disappears from the top middle of the screen at any point, you'll need to restart.

1. Next to the starting peninsula is a river. At the start of it, is a wooden bridge. Jump and dive over this when the water is halfway or higher up.

[image]

2. Swim up this river until you get to the waterfall. You can then jump onto the red climbing grips on the left hand side. Climb these, then jump onto the boost (pop) can to your right.

[image]

3. You will land in a pond. Again climb up the red climbing grips. Careful on the last one, it's easy to accidentally step on land. When at the top, jump onto the boost can.

[image]

4. This will fire you into the pond you need! It's OK if you land on the wooden poles (I did), it still counts.

[image]